# How to properly restart Indy TCP Server for the next client connection?

Tags: android, delphi, tcp, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an Indy TCP server, the client connects to it, send an information, the server receives, create a huge TStringList and send back to the client. This happens thousands of times daily so I decided to put six servers on different .exe doing the same thing on different ports and put the client app to connect each time on a random port.

**What is happening:**

1) The moment from the client first attempt to connect to the moment he receive all the information he needs is pretty high, like he was doing the work twice.

2) Around 10% of the times the client tries to connect and the server seems to ignore the attempt and the client doesn't fire the except to try again, and stuck.

**The server:**

- `MaxConnections` is set to 1
- `ListenQueue` to 0
- `TerminateWaitTime` to 5000
- `ReuseSocket` to False on client and server
- `UsaNagle` := True on client and server

The client 6 second `Timer` that tries to connect to the server:

```
  IdDownloadClient.IOHandler.MaxLineLength := MaxInt;
  IdDownloadClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
  // Choose a random port
  IdDownloadClient.Connect;
  IdDownloadClient.IOHandler.WriteLn(lat+','+long);
  Timer6.Enabled := True;
```

The client `Timer6` (25 ms):

```
  with IdDownloadClient do
  begin
    try
      if IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      begin
        IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0);
        IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
        if IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
        end;
      end;
      receivedtext := IOHandler.ReadLn;
    except
      Timer6.Enabled := False;
      Exit;
    end;
    if receivedtext = '@' then begin // The server send an '@' to say the complete TStringList has been sent
      IdDownloadClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
      IdDownloadClient.IOHandler.CloseGracefully;
      IdDownloadClient.Disconnect;
```

The server `OnExecute` event:

```
begin
try
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
LatLong := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
if LatLong <> '' then begin
latF := StrToFloat(StringReplace(Copy(LatLong,0,ansipos(',',LatLong)-1),'.',',',[rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]));
lonF := StrToFloat(StringReplace(Copy(LatLong,ansipos(',',LatLong)+1,11),'.',',',[rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]));

// Creates a TStringList from a Memo to send (around half a sec of proccessing)
bufferlist := TStringList.Create;
bufferlist.Add('h-023.64086400000,-046.57425900000 99999999 0300 0301 0001 test|123 test');
  for J := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-2 do
    begin
      if ((abs(latF-StrToFloat(StringReplace(Copy(Memo1.Lines[J],2,16),'.',',',[rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]))) < 0.1) and (abs(lonF-StrToFloat(StringReplace(Copy(Memo1.Lines[J],19,16),'.',',',[rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]))) < 0.1)) then
      bufferlist.Add(Memo1.Lines[J]);
    end;

///////// Start to send
  for i := 0 to bufferlist.Count-1 do
    begin
      AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(bufferlist[i]);
    end;

AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('@'); // Send '@' to the client to say the list is over
bufferlist.Free;
end;
except
    if Assigned(bufferlist) then bufferlist.Free;
    Exit;
end;
end;
```

Since all the connections comes from 3G/4G phones I assume that some of them end bad and this is causing the problem, so what am I doing wrong in this code?

There is something I can do for solving this problem or at least improve it?

Comment: Your OnExecute interferes with Indy's connection management in OnExecute by hiding the exception - Indy will not detect connection failures (and terminate the connection) if the exception does not leave the procedure.

Comment: What do you mean by 'leaving the procedure'? How can I fix this?

Comment: @MaurícioLima: Don't catch and discard exceptions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server's `OnExecute` is swallowing all raised exceptions.  When the client disconnects, the next socket I/O performed on that client's socket will raise an exception, which you are catching and discarding.  So the server will not know the client has disconnected, and will continue to fire the `OnExecute` event.  And since your server is set to `MaxConnections=1`, a new client cannot connect to the server until the previous client has been fully released.  Your `OnExecute` code would have to call `AContext.Connection.Disconnect()` directly, or raise an uncaught exception, to release the client thread.

Simple rule of thumb - don't swallow exceptions!  If you catch an exception you don't know how to handle, you should re-raise it, as it may be handled higher up in the call stack.  In terms of `TIdTCPServer`, never swallow an Indy exception that is derived from `EIdException`, let the server handle it.  Your use of a `try/except` just to free `bufferlist` should be replaced with a `try/finally` instead.

In fact, I would suggest getting rid of the `TStringList` for gathering the response data, as it is not actually helping you, it is hindering your server's performance.  The client will not receive any response from the server until the entire `TStringList` has been built in full, and that may cause timeouts on the client side.  It would be better to send each line of text to the client as it is being created, so the client knows the server is actually doing something and is not dead/frozen.

Another problem I see with your `OnExecute` code is that it is directly accessing a UI control (a `TMemo`) without synchronizing with the UI thread.  `TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, its events are fired in worker threads.  You **must** synchronize with the UI thread when accessing UI controls in a worker thread.

And lastly, your overuse of `Copy()` and `StringReplace()` is a major eye-sore and makes the code hard to maintain in general.

Try something more like this instead:

```
procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  // do this assignment one time, not on every OnExecute loop iteration
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8;
end;

procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  s: string;
  latF, lonF: Double;
  fmt: TFormatSettings;
  lines: TStringList;
  j: Integer;
begin
  s := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn;
  if s = '' then Exit;

  fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
  fmt.DecimalSeparator := '.';

  latF := StrToFloat(Fetch(s, ','), fmt);
  lonF := StrToFloat(s, fmt);

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('h-023.64086400000,-046.57425900000 99999999 0300 0301 0001 test|123 test');

  lines := TStringList.Create;
  try
    TThread.Synchronize(nil,
      procedure
      begin
        lines.Assign(Memo1.Lines);
      end
    );

    for J := 0 to lines.Count-2 do
    begin
      s := lines[J];
      if (abs(latF-StrToFloat(Copy(s, 2, 16), fmt)) < 0.1) and (abs(lonF-StrToFloat(Copy(s, 19, 16), fmt)) < 0.1) then
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(s);
    end;
  finally
    lines.Free;
  end;

  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('@'); // Send '@' to the client to say the list is over
end;
```

Now, on the client side, what you are doing is generally fine (though I would suggest using a worker thread instead of a timer in the main UI thread), however I will say that you do not need to call `InputBuffer.Clear()` for a graceful disconnect, only an abnormal disconnect (ie, move it into your `except` handler), and you should not be calling `CloseGracefully()` at all.

Also, since you are terminating the response with a unique delimiter, I would suggest that once the client detects the server's response starting to arrive, it should use `TIdIOHandler.Capture()` to read the entire response in one go, instead of calling `ReadLn()` to read each individual line on each timer event.  That will greatly simplify and speed up how fast the client receives the complete response.

```
procedure Timer6Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  response: TStringList;
begin
  with IdDownloadClient do
  begin
    try
      if IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
      begin
        IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(0);
        IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
        if IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
      end;

      response := TStringList.Create;
      try
        // The server send an '@' to say the complete response has been sent
        IOHandler.Capture(response, '@', False);

        // use response as needed...
      finally
        response.Free;
      end;
    except
      IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;
    end;
    Disconnect;
  end;
  Timer6.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect Remy Lebeau, I really needed these advices.

Comment: Oh gosh, I had to get back here and say THANK YOU REMY these changes made my app download the data from 2~3 seconds to a blink of an eye.